Remote access does not work like localhost
I can install this package and browse using localhost:3000 as address.
git clone https://github.com/allotropia/zetajs.git
cd zetajs/examples/letter-address-tool
npm install
npm start

I got these commands from:
https://zetaoffice.net/demo1.html
But the problem is that it is not accessible remotely.
When they visit:
http://ec2-98-82-174-217.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/
Error:
This site can’t be reached
ec2-98-82-174-217.compute-1.amazonaws.com refused to connect.

I need to enable this to everyone as a demo.

It looks like that listens on 127.0.0.1 by default and you can change the address to listen on with the listen argument, but I'm not sure exactly where you provide that argument. A quick workaround would be changing 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 in gulpfile.js

Tried. That did not work. Still the same error message.

Then you should make sure your AWS firewall isn't blocking port 3000
